# How to hide postal code in SqPaymentForm?

Tags: angular7, square

I am working on angular 7 app. I have integrated SqPaymentForm form but I have not found to hide the postal code SqPaymentForm form.

Please tell me how to hide this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you just need to set `postalCode: false` within the `SqPaymentForm` initializer. See example in our [code cookbook on removing postal code requirement](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/cookbook/remove-postal-code-requirement#step-2-remove-the-postal-code-requirement). This will remove the postal code requirement, but of course you need to actually remove the `div` field that you created to hold the postal code (or hide it if you plan on supporting both countries that do and do not need postal codes).

I'll also add a warning from Square's docs:

> Postal code is a required payment field for processing credit cards issued in the United States (US), Canada (CA), and United Kingdom (GB). Disabling postalCode in those regions will result in all credit card transactions being declined.